# monaca(phonegap)の高速な音声再生法

Tags: android, monaca, html5, iphone, cordova

monacaを用いて，体の動きに合わせて音楽がなるアプリを開発しています． 
現在，[こちら](https://docs.monaca.io/ja/sampleapp/tips/media/)のページの一番下のindex.htmlを参考にして， `playAudio()`関数により音を出しています． 
しかし，体の動きに合わせてなるようにプログラムを組んでいるものの， 
`playAudio()`関数の実行が遅いため，音楽の再生が体の動きについていきません． 
0.5秒くらいの効果音をならせたいだけなのですが， 
より早く音を鳴らせる方法をご存知の方いらっしゃいませんか？

なお，上記URLで指しているプログラムはこちらになります：

Plain Project Skeleton

```
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-image : url("images/omikuji-bg.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            background-size : 100% 100%;
            background-attachment : fixed;
            margin : 0;
            padding : 0;
        }

        #hako {
            width : 100%;
            text-align : center;
            margin : 10% 0px;
            height : 80%;
            position : fixed;
            left : 0;
            top : 0;
        }

        #bottombar {
            position : absolute;
            left : 0px;
            bottom : 30px;
            width : 100%;
        text-align : center;
        }

    </style>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="components/loader.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     //Variables to specify the sound sources. They are used to generate Media objects.
     var src1 = "koukaon1.mp3";
     var src2 = "koukaon2.mp3";
     var src3 = "koukaon3.mp3";

     //In order to use Media objects, these variables must be declared here. Their initial values are null (empty).
     var media1 = null;
     var media2 = null;
     var media3 = null;


    //In Android, it's necessary to specify the absolute path
     function getPath(){
         var str = location.pathname;
         var i = str.lastIndexOf('/');
         return str.substring(0,i+1);
     }

             //Call "onDeviceReady" function when "deviceready" event of the Core Cordova Plugins completed.
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


     function onDeviceReady(){

           alert("Loading Core Cordova Plugins is completed");

                       /*
                        Generating objects to play the sound effect.
                        1st argument [getPath() + src1] indicates the path of the sound file.
                        2nd and 3rd arguments defines a callback function when encounter success and failure respectively.
                       */
           media1 = new Media(getPath() + src1, onSuccess, onError);
           media2 = new Media(getPath() + src2, onSuccess, onError);
           media3 = new Media(getPath() + src3, onSuccess, onError);

    }

         if (typeof Windows != "undefined") {

             window.alert = function(s) {
                 new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(s).showAsync();
             }
         }
         function omikuji (){

             var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

             var image_name;

             //Play a different sound effect for each result.
             if (dice == 0) {
                 image_name = "omikuji-daikichi.png";

                 media1.play();
             } else if  (dice == 1) {
                 image_name = "omikuji-chuukichi.png";

                 media2.play();
             } else {
                 image_name = "omikuji-hei.png";

                 media3.play();
             }

             document.getElementById("saisyo").setAttribute("style", "display : none;");
             document.getElementById("kekka").src = "images/" + image_name;
             document.getElementById("kekka").setAttribute("style", "display : inline;");
             document.getElementById("button").src = "images/omikuji-btn-yarinaosu.png";

             alert('The Fortune is out! What is the result?');
         }

     function onSuccess() {
          console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
     }

     function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
     }

     </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="hako">
        <img src="images/omikuji-box.png" width="160" id="saisyo" />
        <img src="" width="230" id="kekka" style="display : none;"/>
    </div>
    <div id="bottombar">
        <img src="images/omikuji-btn-hajimeru.png" onclick="omikuji()" width="160" id="button">
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: こちらのページ…？どこでしょう。

Comment: 参考にしているページのリンクも勿論貼った方がいいですが、可能であればコードを質問文内に記載していただいた方が、今後リンク先が修正されても質問内容と齟齬が出なくて済みます。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/50458

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございました．
リンク，プログラムともに掲載させていただきました．

Comment: （質問文に転載されている）リンク先の一番下のサンプルではplayAudio関数が使われていませんし、実装も不明です。というか参考にしたコードをどこまで変更されているのかわからないので、いずれにせよ**ご自身で書かれた、問題が起きているコード**を載せていただいた方がよいです。リンク先の保全は二の次です。(cc: @Myaku)

Comment: そうですね、"参考にして～"とあったので中身まで見ていませんでしたが、差分が著しいのであれば、問題になっているコードを添付していただくべきですね。

Answer (score 2):

質問で示されたリンク先にはMediaプラグインを使ったサンプルが二つ載っていますが、それぞれの実装は微妙に異なります。

- [「Cordova のメディア操作プラグインを使用した、音の再生」](https://docs.monaca.io/ja/sampleapp/tips/media/#using-core-cordova-plugins-media-api-to-play-sound)
  ボタンを押すと(playSound)、毎回 `new Media(...)` と `media.play(...)` を行う。
- [「Cordova のメディア操作プラグインを使用した、効果音の再生」](https://docs.monaca.io/ja/sampleapp/tips/media/#using-media-api-to-play-sound-effects)
  あらかじめ `new Media(...)` をしておき、ボタンを押したときは `media.play()` のみを行う。

後者では `new Media(...)` で得られたインスタンスを使いまわすことで、2回目以降の再生では初期化が省略され、再生が素早く行えます。

一方今回のご質問では `playSound()` 関数が～という話をされているので、前者のサンプルを参考にされたのではないでしょうか。それで毎回 `playSound()` を呼び出しているとすると、毎回音声ファイルを読み込むことになりますから、余分なラグが生じる可能性があります。

手元では次のコードで検証しました。タップから再生までのラグもそうですが、連打してみると違いが分かりやすいかと思います。

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">

    <script>
        function getPath(){
            var str = location.pathname;
            var i = str.lastIndexOf('/');
            return str.substring(0,i+1);
        }

        var path = getPath() + "sound.wav";
        var media = null;

        function play (){
            media = new Media(path);
            media.play();
        }

        function play2 (){
            if(media == null)
                media = new Media(path);
            media.play();
        }
    </script>
    <style>
    div { padding: 1em; border: 1px solid gray; background: #fee; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- イベント発生までのラグを減らすためにonclickではなくontouchstart -->
    <div ontouchstart="play()">毎回初期化</div>
    <div ontouchstart="play2()">一度だけ初期化</div>
</body>
</html>
```

なお、ファイル読み込みなどの初期化が行われるのは最初に `media.play()` した時です。再生せず初期化するメソッドは用意されていません。iOSでは[音量を絞って再生する](http://rebrandsoft.blogspot.jp/2014/10/how-to-preload-audio-in-phonegap.html)ことで疑似的に行うことはできるようですが、Androidではこの手は使えませんし、サードパーティのプラグインが必要になるかもしれません。